# Parsing JSON off the main thread using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I need to parse a few JSON files on startup and populate a database with their data. On app startup, a splash screen is shown while the files are parsed.

I would like to perform all parsing off the main thread, and allow loading animations to progress smoothly.

I have been able to create an Observable using RxJava's `Observable.create()` method. The current code is shown below:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
        parseBundles();
        parsePhrases();
    }
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class),
            ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(SplashActivity.this,
            android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).toBundle());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Object o) {

    }
});
```

This successfully makes the `parseBundles()` and `parsePhrases()` methods run on an io thread. For some context, these two methods simply load the local `.json` files using an `InputStream` and throw the `.json` into a `String` variable, where the relevant `JSONObjects` are then pulled out of, and the data saved to a DB.

The issue, however, is that `onCompleted()` is never called. Both the `parseBundles()` and `parsePhrases()` methods are plain old methods, without any Rx code. As I understand it, I need to modify them to properly emit something when finished.

How can I modify this code to work as described? Please note, this is currently written using RxJava 1, however answers using RxJava 2 would be acceptable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Observable is not properly constructed, you need to drive the async process yourself:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
  @Override
  public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
    parseBundles();
    parsePhrases();
    subscriber.onCompleted();
  }
})
```

As an aside, I hate `Observable.create` - it's at too low level and too many people will get it wrong the first two-three times; never understood why tutorials start with that...

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize it was something so simple. Creating and consuming Observables created via the `Observable.from()`, `Observable.just()`, and other similar methods is fairly straightforward. However, I agree, when wrapping custom methods `Observable.create()` is needed and is not as intuitive as it could be.

Comment: It's usually easier to use `Observable.fromCallable` or `Observable.from(Future<?>)`

Comment: `.fromCallable()` looks useful, I will look into it. Also, do you know how this functionality would be implemented using the `Observable.create()` in RxJava 2? It takes an `ObservableOnSubscribe<Object>()` and contains a `subscribe()` method which passes in a `ObservableEmitter<Object> e`. Would it simply be a matter of calling the methods and calling `e.onComplete()` as well?

Comment: Yes, same concept.